# How to replay a previous request in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I've left Postman behind and have been loving Paw. One thing I cannot figure out how to do, though, is replay previous requests.

I have a new request, and I frequently tinker with the JSON. I would like to get back to a previously-sent request and replay it.

I see the clock button on the response section, and can view previous responses. However, is there a way to resend that request without copy-pasting the payload, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the answer I hoped for, but I hit this question trying to find out the same thing (I got sick of Postman creating a new tab for every request)

As far as I can tell you need to create a new request in the left hand side bar and reuse that. Seems you can duplicate for fiddling and keep them, but the Postman(esque) request history doesn't seem to exist.

Putting this here for the next person to stop looking!

Answer (score 0):

You can click the little refresh icon on the right of the URL box.

https://paw.cloud/docs/getting-started/send-request

[image: Paw resend]